# Samsung 970 Evo Plus in PCIe adapter disconnecting when copying large files to it

Tags: ssd, motherboard, connection, pci-express

I've just installed a new Samsung 970 EVO Plus NVMe in my computer as a storage drive for large files plus some swap. I've got an ASUS Rampage IV Extreme motherboard which doesn't have an M.2 slot, so I've put it into this [PCIe adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SupaGeek-PCIe-Express-Adapter-Card/dp/B07CBJ6RH7/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=PCIe+M.2+Adapter&qid=1609873911&sr=8-3) to connect it up.

I've written the filesystem and formatted the drive using `fdisk` with no problems at all, and added the partitions to my `/etc/fstab`: all working there.

The problems are arising when I try to use it: If I try to copy any files larger than maybe 4-5 GB (total) in one go, the drive disconnects and I then can't find it in `lsblk`, `blkid`, etc.
However, if I run `lshw` on it, the entry changes (after breaking) from

```
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E5/Core i7 DMI2
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 IIO PCI Express Root Port 3c
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.2
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:30 memory:fb700000-fb7fffff
           *-nvme
                description: NVMe device
                product: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: /dev/nvme0
                version: 2B2QEXM7
                serial: S4EVNX0NA28772J
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: nvme pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0 nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:144d144dS4EVNX0NA28772J     Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB state=live
                resources: irq:39 memory:fb700000-fb703fff
              *-namespace
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: nvme@0:1
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                   size: 465GiB (500GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: guid=a3d75aac-49c2-6240-a677-e1158ab7a1ab logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 wwid=eui.0025385a01b16726
                 *-volume:0
                      description: Linux swap volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p1
                      version: 1
                      serial: b56f2b45-4fc4-41d0-8a28-2b36776503ec
                      size: 15GiB
                      capacity: 15GiB
                      capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                      configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
                 *-volume:1
                      description: EXT4 volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,2
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                      logical name: /media/NVME
                      version: 1.0
                      serial: 159f0225-1aab-4247-bff2-157f1253e886
                      size: 449GiB
                      capacity: 449GiB
                      capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                      configuration: created=2021-01-05 16:25:59 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/media/NVME modified=2021-01-05 18:58:13 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.
options=rw,relatime mounted=2021-01-05 18:58:13 state=mounted
```

to

```
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E5/Core i7 DMI2
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 IIO PCI Express Root Port 3c
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.2
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:30 memory:fb700000-fb7fffff
           *-nvme UNCLAIMED
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: nvme pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:fb700000-fb703fff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 Address Map, VTd_Misc, System Management
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 Control Status and Global Errors
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 5.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.2
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: PIC
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 I/O APIC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 5.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.4
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm io_x_-apic bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fb82a000-fb82afff
```

I have no idea what's causing this: presumably either the controller is overheating etc. under the sustained load or the motherboard isn't sending the SSD enough power?
Perhaps an issue with the adapter? I've tested this in all the available PCIe slots plus one which had an ethernet card (working stably) in it and the issue is exactly the same in each.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to check whether any of these are the case and googling hasn't returned anything useful.

Comment: The max power consumption for the 970 Evo Plus is 9 Watt in burst mode. And every regular (non-low-profile) PCIe slot should provide 25 Watt.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was just an issue with the the PCIe - M.2 adapter. Buying a new one (different model) resolved the problem.